# Could anyone tell me whether I am on the right track for this problem?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, moment-generating-functions

[image]

Below is my solution for part a, but I don't know how to solve part b. I am also unsure of my part a solution is correct or not.

a)

Since $X$ is exponentially distributed, $f_X(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, for $x \geq 0$

Also we know that, $f_X(x) = 0$, for $x \lt 0$

$F_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda}{M(c)} \int_{x = 0}^{y} e^{cx} e^{-\lambda x} dx = \frac{\lambda}{M(c)} \int_{x = 0}^{y} e^{(c- \lambda)x} dx$

$F_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda}{(c-\lambda)M(c)} e^{(c-\lambda)y} - \frac{\lambda}{(c-\lambda)M(c)}$

So by definition, $f_Y(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda}{M(c)} e^{(c-\lambda)y}$

Where $M(c) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - c}$,as we plug this into the equation

$f_Y(y) = (\lambda - c) e^{(c-\lambda)y}$

b)

By definition

$M_Y(y) = E[e^{cY}] = (\lambda - c) \int e^{cy} e^{(c-\lambda)y} dy$

Comment: What is a "distinguished" $c\in\mathbb R$? Does it just mean for some fixed $c$?

Comment: Actually, I am not so sure abut that....But I think you can regard c as t. Because moment generating function is $M_X(t)$

Comment: For the example with the exponential distribution, the integral should go from $0$ to $y$ since $f_X(x)$ is zero when $x < 0$.

Comment: I see what you mean, thanks.

Comment: edited, but do you know how to forward to the next step?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the density of $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=(\lambda-c)e^{-(\lambda-c)y}$, since it was assumed that $c<\lambda$. From here it follows that the moment-generating function of $Y$ is
$$
M_Y(\theta) = \int_0^\infty e^{\theta y}(\lambda-c)e^{-(\lambda-c)y}\ \mathsf dy = \frac{\lambda-c}{\lambda-(c+\theta)},
$$
which is defined in the neighborhood $(-(\lambda-c),\lambda-c)$ of zero.